# Highlight an anchor tag from a list on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a sidebar of sorts which is populated like this, each link loads different html in another div on the page;

```
<div id = "sidebar-links">

      <% @locations.each do |locs| %>

        <p style = "border-bottom: 1px black solid">
          <a href = "#" class = "sidebar-click" onclick = 'renderLocation(+' <% locs %> +')'><%= locs['Address'] %></a>
        </p>

      <% end %>

</div>
```

I want to highlight each link as it is clicked. Once another link is clicked I want that to be highlighted instead. Currently this is what I am doing;

```
$(document).ready(function() { // Start up jQuery
        $('a.sidebar-click').click(function() {
          $('a.sidebar-click').removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
          $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight');
          return false;
    }); 
    });​
```

And in style;

```
.ui-state-highlight {border: 4px solid #ffffa1; margin-right: 3px;}
```

But this code is not working! How do I do this or what am I doing wrong in my current approach?

Comment: your code looks correct, make sure the styles are not overridden or something

Comment: There seems to be a hidden character at the end of `$(document).ready`. When I paste it into Notepad++ it is followed by a `?`.

Comment: Yea, your code works for me also. Check your html structure and css. Here's a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/GmkLs/

Comment: My bad, it was a hidden character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hidden character at the end of $(document).ready. My bad.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.sidebar-click').click(function(e) {
      var this = $(this);
      $('#sidebar-links a').each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
      });
      this.toggleClass('ui-state-highlight');
      e.preventDefault();
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score -3):

I guess that you don't want the link to be followed, so your code is almost OK but you need to prevent the default event, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { // Start up jQuery

    $('a.sidebar-click').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent following link's href
        $('a.sidebar-click').removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
        $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight');
    });

});​
```

Comment: return false; is handling the preventDefault() action